# Wierd Docker DNS error referencing C file?

Tags: node.js, docker, dns, grpc

I am getting this really weird error from my node.js docker container all of the sudden. I tried googling it but nothing came up. Any advice? :S

```
E0528 02:56:32.124438366     131 resolve_address_posix.c:118]   getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
D0528 02:56:32.124710117     131 dns_resolver.c:186]         dns resolution failed: retrying in 1.000000000 seconds
```

The only thing I can think of is that I recently added `grpc`

Comment: Did you even read the message? And this is not related to the C language.

Comment: @Olaf Hey .. yea I did read the message.. I am not sure how to interpret it. I'm sorry if my reference to the C language in this question was inappropriate, I don't understand the message so I took my best guess at what tags to apply. I'm not sure what I could have done differently. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I have not worked with docker, but to me it seems you try to access a service which does not exist. Read the manpage for the function mentioned in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages are in fact produced by gRPC. They indicate that gRPC failed to resolve a DNS name to an IP address. If one of your RPCs is failing, then this is probably the reason, and you may have initialized a gRPC client with an incorrect domain name. If all of your RPCs are succeeding, then this message may just indicate a transient DNS error.